# Reversing a HashMap storing words and their line numbers

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>> indexMap;
```

which is storing all words in a file and their corresponding line numbers where they appear.

Example -

```
This is just an example
to demonstrate what I am saying an is
```

Would display

```
This [1]
demonstrate [2]
an [1 2]
is [1 2]
...
....
```

And so on. I want to reverse this HashMap so that it displays the words stored at each line number.

For the particular example above, it should display

```
1 [This, an, just, example, is]
2 [demonstrate, what, to, I, am, saying, is, an]
```

For this particular task, this is what I have done -

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReverseIndex {
    private static Map<String, LinkedList<Integer>> indexMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>>();

    public static LinkedList<Integer> getIndex(String word) {
        return indexMap.get(word);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(
                    new FileReader(
                            args[0]));
            String line = "";
            int lineNumber = 0;
            //CREATING THE INITIAL HASHMAP WHICH WE WANT TO REVERSE
            while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;
                String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                    if (getIndex(words[i]) != null)
                        temp = getIndex(words[i]);
                    temp.add(lineNumber);
                    indexMap.put(words[i], temp);
                }
            }
            //FINISHED CREATION

            Map<Integer, LinkedList<String>> myNewHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>>();


            for(Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : indexMap.entrySet()){
                LinkedList<Integer> values = entry.getValue();
                String key = entry.getKey();
                LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<String>();
                for(int i = 0; i <= lineNumber; i++) {
                    if(values.contains(i)) {
                        if(!temp.contains(key))
                            temp.add(key);
                        myNewHashMap.put(i, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, LinkedList<String>> entry : myNewHashMap.entrySet()){
                Integer tester = entry.getKey();
                LinkedList<String> temp2 = new LinkedList<String>();
                temp2 = entry.getValue();
                System.out.print(tester + " ");
                for(int i = 0; i < temp2.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(temp2.get(i) + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            rdr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However the problem with this is, for the example that we had above, it would print -

```
1 example 
2 an
```

How could I reverse it so that it works perfectly with the expected output?

Comment: Looks like you're creating a new List<String> every time you want to add a value to the new map. That'll give you one answer per line. You need only create the new List<String> if you haven't already mapped the line - otherwise you add to it. Look at your variable `temp` and the fact you always do a `put` in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the first for loop in your main with the below code. I have made some changes to you original code as per convention like moved variable declaration out of loop and changed the logic in a way it checks if the LinkedList<'String'> already exists for the line number if so add it to the list or else create a new LinkedList<'String'> and then add word.

```
        LinkedList<Integer> values = null;
        String key = null;
        LinkedList<String> temp = null;
        for(Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : indexMap.entrySet())
        {
            values = entry.getValue();
            key = entry.getKey();
            temp = new LinkedList<String>();

            for(int value : values)
            {
                temp = myNewHashMap.get(value);
                if(temp == null )
                {
                    temp = new LinkedList<String>();
                    myNewHashMap.put(value,temp);
                }
                temp.add(key);
            }
        }
```